# Windows 8.1 - Failed Symbolic Link Caused Windows To Be Unable To Log In

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8.1, symbolic-link, user-profiles

I was needing to have my Users folder on my Hard Dive instead of my SSD where my Operating System is. However, after following the answer provided by @2mc56 on a [Microsoft Community question](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/windows-8-wont-let-me-move-the-appdatalocal-folder/3fd79309-6240-433a-8019-311483f0bda4?page=3&tm=1395092275446), I was unable to log into my account in the Windows startup screen, having an error message saying "The User Profile Service service failed the sign-in; User profile cannot be loaded".

I used the following steps to "attempt" to create the symbolic link for c:\Users to h:\Users:

1. I created a folder in the C-drive "this_is_c" and another in the
   H-drive "this_is_h"
2. I went to the command prompt located under the repair section of the
   Windows Installation Disk
3. Started with entering "A:", I typed in each drive letter and then
   the command "dir" until I found the two folders that were created in
   step 1
4. Once found, I then should have typed "xcopy /e /k /o /h /b f:\Users
   d:\Users" (My C-drive was F, my H-drive was D)
5. I then should have typed in "rd /s f:\Users"
6. Following I should have typed "mlink /d f:\Users d:\Users"
7. Lastly I typed "exit", rebooted, and I am now where I am now stuck.

---

I did type in a couple extra commands, recently, listing out the directories, these follow:

**Directory of d:\**

```
03/17/2014 03:37 PM <DIR> this_is_h
03/17/2014 04:55 PM <DIR> Users

0 File(s) 0 bytes
2 Dir(s) 997,945,907,008 bytes free
```

---

**Directory of D:\Users**

```
03/1702014 04:55 PM <DIR> .
03/1702014 04:55 PM <DIR> ..
08/22/2013 06:45 AM <SYMLINKD> All Users [C:\ProgramData]
08/22/2013 06:45 AM <DIR> Default User
08/22/2013 06:45 AM <DIR> Jesse
08/22/2013 06:45 AM <DIR> Public

0 File(s) 0 bytes
6 Dir(s) 997,956,907,008 bytes free
```

---

**Directory of f:\**

```
03/14/2014 10:06 PM <DIR> .jagex_cache_32
03/15/2014 12:18 AM <DIR> Intel
03/15/2014 12:04 AM <DIR> MSI
03/15/2014 12:49 AM <DIR> NVIDIA
08/22/2013 07:22 AM <DIR> PerfLogs
03/15/2014 02:46 AM <DIR> Program Files
03/14/2014 08:14 PM <DIR> Program Files (x86)
03/17/2014 03:37 PM <DIR> this_is_c
03/17/2014 04:56 PM <SYMLINKD> Users [d:\Users]
03/15/2014 02:09 AM <DIR> Windows
03/14/2014 08:41 PM <DIR> Windows.old

0 File(s) 0 bytes
11 Dir(s) 81,118,056,448 bytes free
```

---

So to say, I am now stuck and in need of assistance to have this done properly so that I can use my Windows again. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated! Thank you.

**Edit:**
I have one thought as to what may be wrong. Out of curiosity, I looked into the C:\, and there was no folder named ProgramData, only recovery.txt.

Comment: Can you log into the Administrator account?

Comment: You might have to use a restoration point ProgramData is required for Windows to function properly

Comment: I can not log into my account which is the administrator if that is what you mean. I didn't delete ProgramData that I am aware of, so I don't know if it moved too.

Comment: Administrator is a default account that exist by default but has to be enabled, you need to locate the folder, figure out what happen to it

Comment: Administrator account doesn't work for some reason. I'd be open to a fresh installation of Windows 8.1 if I knew how to replace the already existing one one my SSD. Goodbye write cycles.

Comment: You last comment does not make a great of sense

Comment: I'm just going to start over fresh. According to Microsoft, there is no going back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled Windows 8.1 and followed [a guide](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/4275-user-profiles-relocate-another-partition-disk-45.html#post358741) provided by a person by the name of Kari. It worked flawlessly.